Am I using Clebsch-Gordan coefficients correctly in my proof of the Wigner-Eckart theorem?
I am trying to derive the Wigner-Eckart theorem from a representation theory perspective, not from the quantum mechanics perspective. For more context, I am a mechanical engineer with more background in groups and representations than quantum mechanics.
I have seen a proof of the general Wigner-Eckart theorem in a textbook that I am following (Group Theory in Solid State Physics and Photonics by Hergert and Geilhufe), but it uses a lot of computations and "tricks", which I have avoided. Since I have not seen this type of a proof (at least in Google searches), I want some thoughts on whether it is correct. I do not want to be fooling myself!
I am mainly concerned with my use of Clebsch-Gordan coefficients in the proof because I am unsure about the concept. (My doubt on Clebsch-Gordan coefficients is posted here: Doubt in representation theory derivation of Clebsch-Gordan coefficients.)
Problem definition:
Let $G$ be a group of coordinate transformations. $G$ acts on $V$, a Hilbert space of functions, as $g f(\mathbf{r}) := f(R(g)^{-1}\mathbf{r})$, where $R(g)$ is a coordinate transformation matrix. $G$ also acts on the space of operators $\mathcal{L}(V,V)$ as $g H (f(\mathbf{r})):=R(g)H(R(g)^{-1}f(\mathbf{r}))$.
Let $W_p$ be an irreducible representation in $V$ with a basis $\{\phi^p_j\}_{j=1}^{\mathrm{dim}W_p}$ and matrix elements $\{\Gamma^p_{ij}(g)\}$. Similarly, let $W_q$ be an irreducible representation in $\mathcal{L}(V,V)$ with a basis $\{H^q_k\}_{i=1}^{\mathrm{dim}W_q}$ and matrix elements $\{\Gamma^q_{ij}(g)\}$. Similarly, let $W_r$ be an irreducible representation in $V$ with a basis $\{\phi^r_j\}_{j=1}^{\mathrm{dim}W_r}$ and matrix elements $\{\Gamma^r_{ij}(g)\}$.
To show: $$\langle \phi^r_i(\mathbf{r}) | H^q_k(\phi^p_j(\mathbf{r})) \rangle =\sum_{\alpha} c^{pq;jk}_{ir\alpha} \langle r | H^q | p \rangle_\alpha \;,$$
where $c^{pq;jk}_{ir\alpha}$ are Clebsch-Gordan coefficients and the term $\langle r | H^q | p \rangle_\alpha$ depends on the choice of irreducible representations $W_p$, $W_q$, and $W_r$ alone, and not on the row indices $i,j,k$.
Proof:
We can define the tensor product of representations $W_p \otimes W_q$ in the usual way with a basis $\{\phi^p_j  \otimes H^q_k \}_{j,k}$. We can also define a morphism of representations $F:W_p \otimes W_q \to V$ as $F(\phi^p_j  \otimes H^q_k) = H^q_k(\phi^p_j)$.
Let $W_p \otimes W_q$ decompose into irreducible components as $\oplus_s n_s W_s$. Let $\{\psi^{s,\alpha}_i | s=1,\dots,C ; \; \alpha = 1,\dots,n_r ; \; i=1,\dots,\dim W_s\}$ be a basis of $F(W_p \otimes W_q)$, where $C$ is the number of distinct irreducible representations of $G$. Note that the basis depends on the choice of irreducible representations $p$ and $q$.

By the concept of Clebsch-Gordan coefficients, we can write
$$ H^q_k(\phi^p_j(\mathbf{r})) = \sum_{l,s,\alpha} 
 c^{pq;jk}_{ls\alpha} \psi^{s,\alpha}_l(\mathbf{r})$$

Finally, taking the inner product with $\phi^r_i(\mathbf{r})$,
$$\begin{align} \langle \phi^r_i(\mathbf{r}) | H^q_k(\phi^p_j(\mathbf{r})) \rangle &= \sum_{l,s,\alpha} c^{pq;jk}_{ls\alpha} \langle \phi^r_i(\mathbf{r}) |\psi^{s,\alpha}_l(\mathbf{r}) \rangle \\
&=\sum_{\alpha} c^{pq;jk}_{ir\alpha} \langle \phi^r_i(\mathbf{r}) |\psi^{r,\alpha}_i(\mathbf{r}) \rangle
\end{align}$$
where I make use of orthogonality between functions corresponding to different irreducible representations or different rows of the same irreducible representation. The inner product term on the RHS depends only on $r,\alpha,p,q$. (Recall that $\psi^{r,\alpha}_i$ depends on $p$,$q$.) We can define it as the "reduced matrix element" $\langle r | H^q | p \rangle_\alpha$. Thus, we arrive at
$$\langle \phi^r_i(\mathbf{r}) | H^q_k(\phi^p_j(\mathbf{r})) \rangle =\sum_{\alpha} c^{pq;jk}_{ir\alpha} \langle r | H^q | p \rangle_\alpha \;,$$
which is the Wigner-Eckart theorem.

Hi! proof-verification questions here need a bit of focus on what, exactly, you think might be wrong with your proof - which aspects seem subtle, e.g.

Thanks, added my confusion with Clebsch-Gordon coefficients as the source of uncertainty in the proof.


By the concept of Clebsch-Gordan coefficients, we can write
$$ H^q_k(\phi^p_j(\mathbf{r})) = \sum_{l,s,\alpha}
c^{pq;jk}_{ls\alpha} \psi^{s,\alpha}_l(\mathbf{r})$$

Is this the main concern?

Yes. As mentioned in my linked question, I am not fully convinced about the equation introducing the clebsch-gordan coefficients.

Ok. I’ve made a small edit. The only reason is, proof-verification questions are often unpopular and unfocused so reframing the question (slightly) is better for all involved
